# php preg replace with conditions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

hello I want to replace this code of css:

```
background:url("/media/image.png")
```

and I have a url

```
$url3 ="http://example.com";
```

here is the code I'm using :

```
preg_replace('~url\(("|\')?/?(.*?)(?:\1)?\)~', 'url($1'.$url3.'/$2$1)', background:url("/media/image.png");
```

the output of this code gives me :

```
background:url("http://example.com/media/image.png")
```

and this is what I want , but my problem is I want to add some conditions to my regex for example if the url have `//` or `http` or `https` at start then ignore it don't add http://example.com/ to it.

this is the regex I have tried :

```
~url\(("|\')?/?(.*?)(?:\1)?\)~(((?!'|\"|http://|https://|//).)*)(['\"])-i
```

but it didn't work ..

Comment: maybe use parse_url() http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: This is your third question on this topic in the past 24 hours. Why not leave one open and explain your question. State **exactly** what you are trying, what you have, and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hard-coding the replacement I think it would be easiest to just do another check:

```
if (false === preg_match("~url\((\"|')(//|https?://)~", $string)) {
    // do replacement
}
```

Also note that the argument to `url()` in CSS does not require quoting (`"` or `'`).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a negative look around:

```
url\(("|\')((?!http://|https://).*?)(?:\1)\)
```

You can watch it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/oH2hP4/1).

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
$string = preg_replace(
    '/url\(("|\')(?!https?)\/?(.+?)(?:\1)/',
    'url(\1http://example.com/$2\1',
    $string
)
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words to your code snippet explaining why and how it does answer the OP question

Comment: @b.enoit.be It is all regexp syntax)) what exactly do you need ?

Comment: Me, nothing, your answer was in the low quality answer queue due to the fact that it is all but code and that the OP may not understand it at all ? And that further reader neither.